# React Native how to hide drawer navigation header only on certain screens inside inner stack?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a drawer navigation in my app that contains multiple components/screens one of those components is a stack navigation that consists of multiple screens as well, the thing is i want to hide the drawer header on a certain screen of the inner stack only and continue to show it on the other screens of the stack.
my code is like this

drawer

```
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" >
              <Drawer.Screen name="main" component={MyStack} /> //this is the inner stack
              <Drawer.Screen name="track" component={ProgressTrackerScreen} />
              <Drawer.Screen name="reminder" component={DailyReminderScreen} />
              <Drawer.Screen name="bookmarks" component={BookmarksScreen} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
```

stack

```
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="MainScreen" screenOptions={{
      headerTitleAlign: "right",
      header: () => null
    }} >
      <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={MainScreen} options={{
          title: 'Main', //i want an option here to hide the drawer nav header on this screen only
        }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="page" component={Page} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `navigation.getParent()` method for it.
Firstly, you need make change in stack like this,

```
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="MainScreen" screenOptions={{
      headerTitleAlign: "right",
      headerShown: false,
    }}>
      <Stack.Screen name="MainScreen" component={MainScreen} options={{
          title: 'Main', //i want an option here to hide the drawer nav header on this screen only
          headerShown: true,
        }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="page" component={Page} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
```

After that you can remove drawer navigation header bar in screen like this,
I assume that you are using functional component,

`MainScreen.js/MainScreen.tsx`

```
 const navigation = useNavigation();
 useEffect(() => {
    navigation.getParent()?.setOptions({
      headerShown: false,
    });
    return () =>
      navigation.getParent()?.setOptions({
        headerShown: true,
      });
  }, [navigation]);
```

This is work for me, hope it may help you.